# Splitting matrix or dataset in R by dependent column

Tags: r, matrix, set

Here is a simple, yet ridiculously painstaking process for me.
I am trying to figure out how I can make a set of matrices from a data.

If you have R,

do

```
data(iris)
dim(iris)

[1] 150   5
```

is the dimesion

iris is data given in R programming

When you do

```
iris(3)
dim(iris3)

[1] 50  4  3
```

you get a set of three matrices divided into "Species" dependent column

how do I program/code so I could do this for other dataset???

Thank you for your time and visit

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. `iris(3)` doesn't do anything and throws an error here.

Comment: (+1) @juba. Not so clear as well. My guess is that you're looking for `split(iris, iris$Species)`.

Comment: Yes, split(iris,iris$Species) is what I would want, but split(iris,iris$Species) has all the Species name column. Notice how iris3 has three matrices of 50 by 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `abind` function from `abind` package:

```
> library(abind)
> IrisArray <- abind(split(iris[, -5], iris[,5]), along=3)
> dim(IrisArray)
[1] 50  4  3  # these are the dimensions you want.
```

If you want a function for this, then take a look at this:

```
library(abind)
Splitbyfactor <- function(x, by='Species'){
  ind <-  which(colnames(x)==by)
  abind(split(x[, -ind], x[,ind]), along=3)
}

dim(Splitbyfactor(iris,  by='Species'))
[1] 50  4  3
```

Edit

This edit is for answering your comment, suppose you have a data.frame called `df` consisting of two columns of random numbers and a third col containing ID's, these ID are capital letters A,B,C,D,E and F, this means you have 5 different ID to split by, then `along` argument in the `abind` call does not have to be set to 5, because it does not refer to the number of ID's it refers to the dimensions of the resulting array ;). See this example

```
> df <- data.frame(A=rnorm(10), B=rnorm(10), ID=rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=6)) 
> dim(df)
[1] 30  3
> dim(Splitbyfactor(df,  by='ID'))
[1] 6 2 5
```

Comment: This is great, but is there a way where I can have along greater than 3? Since Iris has 3 species, it seems to be 3, but my data needs 10.

Comment: `along` is the dimension along which to bind the arrays, if your data has 10 `species` it will be taken into account and `Splitbyfactor` will give you what you are expecting. ;)